# POSTGRESQL - trying to update DB while query is running

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update my database with a value while another query is running. I tried using pg_sleep but it ignores any updates to the DB, heres my query :

```
myfunc(){
     return db.many(`SELECT * FROM users, pg_sleep(10) WHERE looking=true`)
};
```

while that query is running , im trying to update the DB live as it searches:

```
UPDATE users SET looking=true WHERE id=1;
```

the query waits 10 seconds, but doesn't notice any updates coming in, is there something other than pg_sleep i can use? or how can i solve this issue?

Comment: A `select` statement does not see any changes to the data while it's running (it would be horrible if it did, as that would make correct aggregations impossible).

Comment: thank you, i've solved my problem by doing a SELECT pg_sleep first, then executing my second select statement. I hope this helps anyone in the future who was trying to accomplish the same task

Comment: Some kind of inter-process communication would be the best solution.